# How to Load/Stress Test TFS

Tags: tfs, load-testing, stress-testing

I'm looking for some ways to load/stress test a new TFS installation. I've never done anything like this before, so I'm not 100% sure on where to begin.

How do you guys do it?

I'm thinking I could script some (maybe all?) of these tests, if I knew what they were. :)

Comment: What do you want to get out of this testing? Do you want to measure average time for most common operations?
For sure you can script Version Control and WorkItem Tracking operations using TFS object model and run them against your server.

You can also check out Microsoft hardware recommendations for different TFS configurations: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592.aspx)

Comment: Very sorry for the delay on this one. I've been away for a few days. The main thing I want to get out of this testing is to ensure that I have sized my VMs appropriately.